# Is there a way to determine if a project that is running is a .war or a .jar file?

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way to check to see if the project that is currently running is a .jar or .war file? I am trying to get the class path but it of course is different based on whether it is a .war file or not.

```
String classPath = new File(Class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
                            .toURI()).getPath();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine if a project that is running is a `.war` or a `.jar` file?

I think that the answer is "no there isn't".

First ... what does it mean to *"run a .war"*?

Out of the box Java SE does not understand WAR files.  `java -cp my.war ...` won't work. WAR files are a Java EE thing.

Likewise, an out of the box Java EE (or Jakarta EE) web container cannot run an ordinary JAR file with a `public static void main(String[])` entry point.

In a typical Java EE container you don't directly "run" a WAR file.  Instead you *typically* deploy it to the Java EE container (e.g. Tomcat, Websphere, etc).  The container will then *unpack* the WAR into a directory and run the webapp from that directory, using a classloader that reads JAR files and `.class` files it finds within the directory.

(This is why the code in your question is unlikely to work.  Resources on the webapp's classpath probably won't have `war:` URIs.  They will have `jar:` or `file:` URIs ... referring to the unpacked WAR contents.)

But even if you call what (say) Tomcat does "running a WAR file" there is still an issue.  With Tomcat can configure your IDE to populate the webapp directory directly, avoiding the need to create a WAR file at all.  Or (shudder!) you can do your development in the Tomcat webapp dir directly.

As far as I am aware, a webapp *cannot* distinguish the two modes of deployment, and (therefore) cannot tell if it is running out of a JAR file or a WAR file.

On the other hand, a Java application (or library) can probably figure out if it is running in a Java EE (or Jakarta EE) container.  If it is, it will be able to (for example) load `Servlet` classes using reflection.

---

If we are talking about a specific framework (such as Spring Boot) that supports both running JAR and WAR-based applications, then the app may be able to use that framework's capabilities to distinguish the two cases.  (But it is probably not a useful distinction to make ...)